# SWIProlog conditional sum inside list and rebuild

Tags: list, prolog

one of my predicates gives me a list like this as output:

```
[m(1,2,[v(1,y),v(1,y)]),m(1,6,[v(1,y),v(5,x)]),m(1,4,[v(3,x),v(1,y)]),m(1,8,[v(3,x),v(5,x)])]
```

When the symbols inside the sublist with `v` elements are equal (like `y` here):

```
[v(1,y),v(1,y)]
```

or `x` here:

```
[v(3,x),v(5,x)]
```

I have to sum the numbers on the left and rebuild the list like this:

```
[m(1,2,[v(2,y)]),m(1,6,[v(1,y),v(5,x)]),m(1,4,[v(3,x),v(1,y)]),m(1,8,[v(8,x)])]
```

I have a similar predicate that works on the main lists but I am not getting this one right.

This is the other predicate that is working:

```
simplify([], []) :- !.
simplify([X], [X]) :- !.
simplify([m(C, TD, Var), m(C2, TD, Var)| Xs], Ys) :- 
    sumxp(C, C2, K), simplify([m(K, TD, Var)|Xs], Ys), !.
simplify([X, Y|Xs], [X|Ys]) :- !, simplify([Y|Xs], Ys).

sumxp(Power1, Power2, TotalPower) :- TotalPower is Power1 + Power2.
```

It acts in this way:

```
simplify([m(2,2,[v(1,a)]),m(2,2,[v(1,a)])],R).
R = [m(4, 2, [v(1, a)])].
```

Comment: In your example why is `[v(3,x),v(5,x)]` converted to `[v(8,x)]` is there another rule, or is the example wrong?

Comment: When the symbol is the same, x here, I must sum them, so [v(3,x),v(5,x)] became [v(5+3,x)] = [v(8,x)]. Like before [v(1,y),v(1,y)] became [v(2,y)].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `simplify_01` rule works on each item in the list, e.g. `m(1,6,[v(1,y),v(5,x)])`

```erlang
simplify_01(m(A,B,[v(X,Var1),v(Y,Var2)]),m(A,B,[v(X,Var1),v(Y,Var2)])) :-
    Var1 \= Var2.
simplify_01(m(A,B,[v(X,Var1),v(Y,Var1)]),m(A,B,[v(Z,Var1)])) :-
    Z is X + Y.
```

and the `maplist` just applies `simplify_01` to all the items in the list.

```erlang
simplify(L,R) :-
    maplist(simplify_01,L,R).
```

when run using SWI-Prolog

```erlang
simplify([m(1,2,[v(1,y),v(1,y)]),m(1,6,[v(1,y),v(5,x)]),m(1,4,[v(3,x),v(1,y)]),m(1,8,[v(3,x),v(5,x)])],R).
R = [m(1, 2, [v(2, y)]), m(1, 6, [v(1, y), v(5, x)]), m(1, 4, [v(3, x), v(1, y)]), m(1, 8, [v(8, x)])] ;
false.
```